# How to record accuracy for every iteration during sess.run in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am following the code https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py here to build a multilayer perceptron to solve MNIST problem.

In the following code,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                            Y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost={:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

I want to record the accuracy for each iteration, still using `sess.run`; how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have code to measure the training accuracy?  You need to run that block, as well.  Stick it at the bottom of the `Loop over all batches` block, so that it runs for each iteration.

If you want the loss, rather than the accuracy, then simply print `avg_cost` at that spot.  If you want the loss printed for every *epoch*, rather than every iteration, then remove the modulo conditional `if epoch % display_step == 0:` and un-indent the `print` after that.

Did one of those hit what you need?